# google ima sdk video paused when ads skipped

Tags: ios, swift, google-ima, video-ads

I am using below vast xml sample for displaying pre, mid and post video ads in my video

```
<vmap:VMAP xmlns:vmap="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vmap" version="1.0">
<vmap:AdBreak timeOffset="start" breakType="linear" breakId="preroll">
<vmap:AdSource id="preroll-ad-1" allowMultipleAds="false" followRedirects="true">
<vmap:AdTagURI templateType="vast3">
<![CDATA[
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?slotname=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&sz=640x480&ciu_szs=300x250&unviewed_position_start=1&output=xml_vast3&impl=s&env=vp&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=0&vad_type=linear&vpos=preroll&pod=1&ppos=1&lip=true&min_ad_duration=0&max_ad_duration=30000&vrid=6256&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpost&url=https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/tags&video_doc_id=short_onecue&cmsid=496&kfa=0&tfcd=0
]]>
</vmap:AdTagURI>
</vmap:AdSource>
</vmap:AdBreak>
<vmap:AdBreak timeOffset="00:00:15.000" breakType="linear" breakId="midroll-1">
<vmap:AdSource id="midroll-1-ad-1" allowMultipleAds="false" followRedirects="true">
<vmap:AdTagURI templateType="vast3">
<![CDATA[
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?slotname=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&sz=640x480&ciu_szs=300x250&unviewed_position_start=1&output=xml_vast3&impl=s&env=vp&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=0&cue=15000&vad_type=linear&vpos=midroll&pod=2&mridx=1&ppos=1&lip=true&min_ad_duration=0&max_ad_duration=30000&vrid=6256&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpost&url=https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/tags&video_doc_id=short_onecue&cmsid=496&kfa=0&tfcd=0
]]>
</vmap:AdTagURI>
</vmap:AdSource>
</vmap:AdBreak>
<vmap:AdBreak timeOffset="end" breakType="linear" breakId="postroll">
<vmap:AdSource id="postroll-ad-1" allowMultipleAds="false" followRedirects="true">
<vmap:AdTagURI templateType="vast3">
<![CDATA[
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?slotname=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&sz=640x480&ciu_szs=300x250&unviewed_position_start=1&output=xml_vast3&impl=s&env=vp&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=0&vad_type=linear&vpos=postroll&pod=3&ppos=1&lip=true&min_ad_duration=0&max_ad_duration=30000&vrid=6256&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpost&url=https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/tags&video_doc_id=short_onecue&cmsid=496&kfa=0&tfcd=0
]]>
</vmap:AdTagURI>
</vmap:AdSource>
</vmap:AdBreak>
</vmap:VMAP>
```

The ads url is different.
Everything working fine. All ads all showing. But when I am trying to skip any ads on click on skip button then video paused.

Comment: "But when I am trying to skip any ads on click on skip button" - and how are you doing that?

Comment: On skip button ad skipped but video paused

Comment: see video in https://www.dropbox.com/s/dytrgq520znktov/VID_20190214_1303111.mov?dl=0